# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). IF Statements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

```
import requests
url ="https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/profile/AAPL?apikey=demo"
data = requests.get(url).json()
data_pd = pd.DataFrame(data)

if data_pd["price"] >= data_pd["dcf"]:
```

I get an error on the very last line. I don't understand why this is throwing an error because I am just comparing the header value and there is only one possible value for "price" and "dcf".

Comment: One value or not, `data_pd['price'] >= data_pd['dcf']` is still a series and you cannot convert that into a single boolean.

Comment: Are you saying that the json data you are loading only has a single value for these two keys? Then why use a dataframe at all? A dataframe column can  have any number of items. It may be that yours only has one, but the dataframe isn't programmed for that special case.

Comment: when I lconvert it into a dataframe and print(data_pd["price"]) it prints out its price and it does that for the dcf value as well